# Why does VS Code recognize .releaserc correctly as YAML file, while it does not detect .prettierrc as such?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Both are valid YAML files without extension and both files have `---` as the first line.
There are no associations in my user or workspace settings of VS Code to associate either filename with `yaml`.